# change a word in a line of text file with php

Tags: php, file, preg-replace

I need to change the word just after **Maildir**, in this exemple  **NULL** of a line : (the word NULL can be any word.)

```
  [3]=>
  string(42) "SPAM
* ^Subject: \[SPAM\].*
Maildir/.NULL/"
```

I use this code :

```
if($filecontent = file_get_contents($filename)){

    $repertoire = "SPAM";
    $tab = explode("#", trim($filecontent));
    $tab[3] = preg_replace("#Maildir/*#", 'Maildir/.'.$repertoire.'/', $tab[3]);

    var_dump($tab);
```

But i have

```
  string(48) "SPAM
* ^Subject: \[SPAM\].*
Maildir/.NULL/.SPAM/"
```

How can i change that in **Maildir/.SPAM** because **.NULL** is in excess.

```
  string(48) "SPAM
* ^Subject: \[SPAM\].*
Maildir/.SPAM/"
```

Comment: because the word **NULL** can be any word.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 preg_replace('~Maildir/\K\.NULL/(?=\.SPAM)~', '', $string);
```

or for any word:

```
 preg_replace('~Maildir/\K[\w.-]++/(?=\.SPAM)~', '', $string);
```

I have tested with:

```
$string = <<<LOD
SPAM
* ^Subject: \[SPAM\].*
Maildir/.NULL/.SPAM/
LOD;
echo preg_replace('~Maildir/\K[\w.-]++/(?=\.SPAM)~', '', $string).'<br/>';
echo preg_replace('~Maildir/\K\.NULL/(?=\.SPAM)~', '', $string).'<br/>';
```

Comment: If i try **preg_replace('~Maildir/\K\.[\w.-]++/(?=\.SPAM)~', '', $filecontent);** , nothing change. Same for the first solution.

Comment: @MartialE: do you have made an `echo` before? I an edited my post with a test code. If it don't work with your string, please post the string you try.

Comment: Yeah, it's work but wit two step : first i explode and preg_replace, i have **Maildir/.NULL/.SPAM/**, an after i use your solution. No solution to do that directly ? 1) **Maildir/.NULL/** to **Maildir/.SPAM/** ?